# Regex: searching for groups excluding a character while using a negated method of searching C++

Tags: c++, regex, string

I am using default Visual Studio 2017 Community version. I just finished my parsing model for my bignum implementation.But now
I stumbled across a problem when introducing formulars to my class. it's a string / regex problem.

Consider this string with variables and constants:

```
std::string formular_str = "1 + x * y / 2";
```

Passing this string into parsing functions also requires a vector (with size of 2, since there are 2 variables) of type int (in this example)

```
std::vector<int> vec{ 5, 4 };
```

As these are mapped to the variables (`x` and `y`)

Before breaking down the pre-processing process, you need to understand that I can't filter the constants (`1` and `2` in this example) in a `"[0-9]+"` manner, since I'm using higher bases and therefore use more characters (152 characters from ASCII, to be exact). That means that i define the numbers by the absence of operators (`+`, `-`, `*` and `/` for this examples sake). It works, because these operators are excluded from the bignum base table. Note: variables follow a `"[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*"` manner (`x` and `y` in this example)

In order to use operators and non-operator strings for searching, I remove all whitespace near operators:

```
std::smatch matches;
std::regex reg_whitespace_near_operator("[\\s]+([\\+\\-\\*\\/])[\\s]+");
while (std::regex_search(formular_str, matches, reg_whitespace_near_operator, std::regex_constants::format_first_only)) {
    formular_str = std::regex_replace(formular_str, reg_whitespace_near_operator, matches.str(1), std::regex_constants::format_first_only);
}
```

`formular_str` (`"1 + x * y / 2"`) now looks like this: `"1+x*y/2"`

Next, I replace all variables (`x`, `y`) with `#` + an incrementing index.
I use `#` in parsing to indicate indecies of `vec`.

```
std::regex reg_variable("[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*");

unsigned ctr = 0;
while (std::regex_search(formular_str, reg_variable, std::regex_constants::format_first_only)) {
    formular_str = std::regex_replace(formular_str, reg_variable, std::string("#") + std::to_string(ctr++), std::regex_constants::format_first_only);
}
```

`formular_str` (`"1+x*y/2"`) now looks like this: `"1+#0*#1/2"`

The model will correctly interpret `#0` and `#1` as `vec[0]` and `vec[1]`.

In the end I want my string and vector to look like this:

```
"#2+#0*#1/#3"
{5, 4, 1, 2}
```

But here's where the pre-processing fails. Trying to push_back() the constants `1`
 and `2` to the vector and replacing it with `#2` and `#3` without getting stuck in an endless loop.

```
std::regex reg_constant("[^\\+\\-\\*\\/]+");
while (std::regex_search(formular_str, matches, reg_constant, std::regex_constants::format_first_only)) {
    //std::cout << "matches.str(0) = " << matches.str(0) << ", formular_str = " << formular_str << std::endl;
    vec.push_back(std::atoi(matches.str(0).c_str()));
    formular_str = std::regex_replace(formular_str, reg_constant, std::string("#") + std::to_string(ctr++), std::regex_constants::format_first_only);
}
```

which is an endless loop:

```
matches.str(0) = 1, formular_str = 1+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = #2, formular_str = #2+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = #3, formular_str = #3+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = #4, formular_str = #4+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = #5, formular_str = #5+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = #6, formular_str = #6+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = #7, formular_str = #7+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = #8, formular_str = #8+#0*#1/2
...
```

The first match was correct, but than it just kept getting stuck on the first number. It doesn't even reach `2`. So one idea was to treat `#` like an operator and exclude it from the match:

```
std::regex reg_constant("[^\\+\\-\\*\\/\\#]+");
```

Which produces this pattern:

```
matches.str(0) = 1, formular_str = 1+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = 2, formular_str = #2+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = 3, formular_str = ##3+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = 4, formular_str = ###4+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = 5, formular_str = ####5+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = 6, formular_str = #####6+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = 7, formular_str = ######7+#0*#1/2
matches.str(0) = 8, formular_str = #######8+#0*#1/2
...
```

I also tried `std::sregex_iterator` but it got stuck, too.
I am clueless at this point, I also considered using multiple layers of filtering with an additional `std::regex_search` and `std::regex_replace` inside the while loop, but it failed since it wouldn't alter the formular_str to break the while loop. So it must be the regex to identify the correct string, but I can't seem to get it correct. Please help me!

Full code (with additional std::couts)

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{ 5, 4 };
    std::string formular_str = "1 + x * y / 2";

    std::cout << "Starting formular: " << formular_str << std::endl;

    std::smatch matches;
    std::regex reg_whitespace_near_operator("[\\s]+([\\+\\-\\*\\/])[\\s]+");
    while (std::regex_search(formular_str, matches, reg_whitespace_near_operator, std::regex_constants::format_first_only)) {
        formular_str = std::regex_replace(formular_str, reg_whitespace_near_operator, matches.str(1), std::regex_constants::format_first_only);
    }
    std::cout << "Whitespace removed: " << formular_str << std::endl;

    std::regex reg_variable("[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*");

    unsigned ctr = 0;
    while (std::regex_search(formular_str, reg_variable, std::regex_constants::format_first_only)) {
        formular_str = std::regex_replace(formular_str, reg_variable, std::string("#") + std::to_string(ctr++), std::regex_constants::format_first_only);
    }

    std::cout << "Variables replaced: " << formular_str << std::endl;

    std::regex reg_constant("[^\\+\\-\\*\\/]+");
    while (std::regex_search(formular_str, matches, reg_constant, std::regex_constants::format_first_only)) {
        std::cout << "matches.str(0) = " << matches.str(0) << ", formular_str = " << formular_str << std::endl;
        vec.push_back(std::atoi(matches.str(0).c_str()));
        formular_str = std::regex_replace(formular_str, reg_constant, std::string("#") + std::to_string(ctr++), std::regex_constants::format_first_only);
    }

    std::cout << "Finished formular: " << formular_str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'd advise using a different method such as a shunting yard or recursive descent parser. They're well studied and fairly easy to get to work correctly (and the approach you're taking will still require something similar after you've complete the part you're working on right now).

Comment: I already finished the parsing with all priority rules / precedences and such. It's just about the string pre-processing

Comment: The point is that it'll be much easier to just retrieve the operand and put it on the stack as you parse, rather than trying to do the replacement ahead of time, and pass the correct values as parameters.

Comment: But it has nothing to do with parsing, it's just replacing groups in a string without getting stuck where I need help. maybe I should re-write it

Comment: You're right, but it's still easy to have your lexer retrieve (for example) `x`, and simply look up the value of `x` in your symbol table, and be done with it.

Comment: `x` is not a digit, it's a variable (in this context)

Comment: Yes, that's why you look it up in the symbol table rather than just converting it as  a literal.